# Using regex (preg_match) to find weather data

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse some weather forecast lines for chance of rain and temperatures.  Here is a sample line:

```
$str = 'Mostly cloudy with a 50 percent chance of rain. Highs 45 
        to 50. Lows around 40.'
```

The pattern is always the same.  For rain, I just need the number before the word "percent". For temperature, I need the last number in the sentence for "Highs" and then "Lows".

So far I am doing the following using PHP:

```
//Chance of rain
preg_match('((\d+) (percent))', $str, $match);
$rain_percentage = str_replace(' percent', '', $match[0]);

//High temperature
$high_temp_line = spliti('highs', $str);
preg_match('((\d+)[.])', $high_temp_line[1], $match);
$high_temp = str_replace('.', '', $match[0]);
```

So that is the most efficient way I can think to get what I need.  Is there a better way?

Comment: LOL, yeah, that would help, huh?  Just wondering if there is a more efficient way of getting those stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need, provided the format is always exactly the same:

```
<?php
$str = 'Mostly cloudy with a 50 percent chance of rain. Highs 45 to 50. Lows around 40.';
$regex = '/(.*?) with a (\d*) percent chance of rain. Highs (\d*) to (\d*). Lows around (\d*)./';
$matches = array();
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
```

If you want them all in individual variables instead of being in an array, simply add this line:

```
list($str, $situation, $rain_chance, $highs_high, $highs_low, $lows) = $matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always just those 3 numbers in the string, just use preg_match to pull them out of the string. $matches will be an array containing the matched numbers.

```
preg_match("/(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)/", $str, $matches)
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. Thanks for the quick response though!  Your solution would work, but I meant the pattern was more of first couple sentences will either be chance of rain or wind conditions.  Then the next sentences will be about the temperature.  The pattern I meant was that the rain sentence will always have the word "percent" in it and the temperature sentences will always say "High" or "Lows".